# Loading more than one libraries in CodeIgniter - PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to load more than 2 libraries in a CI Controller and call their member functions. I've tried the following ways but no use.

1.

```
    $this->load->library('liba');
    $result = $this->liba->SearchTours($searchParams);
    echo $result;

    $this->load->library('libb');
    $result2 = $this->libb->tourFetch($searchParams);
    echo $result2;
```

2.

```
    $this->load->library(array('liba' , 'libb'));

    $result = $this->liba->SearchTours($searchParams);
    echo $result;
    $result2 = $this->libb->tourFetch($searchParams);
    echo $result2;
```

3.

```
    $this->load->library('liba');
    $this->load->library('libb');

    $result = $this->liba->SearchTours($searchParams);
    echo $result;
    $result2 = $this->libb->tourFetch($searchParams);
    echo $result2;
```

4.

```
    public function __construct(){
      parent::__construct();
      $this->load->library('liba');
      $this->load->library('libb');
    }
```

5. I have swapped the order of loading in above 4 cases. Whichever is mentioned second does not load.

In all the cases only the first mentioned library is loaded and this Notice shows for the second one.

`A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message:  Undefined property: Unify::$libb
Filename: controllers/Unify.php
Line Number: 30`

I couldn't find any soultion on CI user manual or SO. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think the problem in your library libb, not in count of them. It is normal to load some libraries for Codeigniter

Comment: I tried swapping (loading libb first and then liba). libb loads successfully but liba doesn't.

Comment: load this in construct

Comment: it is your file controllers/Unify.php , not system, i think

Comment: @Abdulla Thanks for the suggestion. I have tried that too. Problem not solved :(.

Comment: @splash58 I'm not sure what you mean. Unify.php is the controller where the above code is written.

Comment: Show us the code of any library. At least, a construct

Comment: try to call one library at a time and see if it works, I think you have a problem with one library either liba or libb

Comment: The problem at loading moment or while calling property? Put any  echo after loading

Comment: @Nassim I tried loading one at a time. Both work perfectly in isolation.

Comment: @splash58 Problem while calling the member function.
`Fatal error:  Call to a member function tourFetch() on a non-object in blahblah\controllers\Unify.php on line 37`

tourFetch() is member function of libb

Comment: I think the error may be found only by reading all your code. I load several  libraries in my project, it works

Comment: @splash58 My library files' function I'm calling contain SOAP XML calls to third party APIs.. Two library files, two different SOAP calls to two different APIs. they return strings.

Comment: ok, if both libraries are calling other controllers , you will have a problem, use $CI =& get_instance(); inside the libraries instead of $this->xxx->yyy() and then call you instance like so : $your_variable = $CI->xxx->yyy()

Comment: @Nassim Ok this might be a problem. Can the library files be controllers?? Because I need to load other libraries in those libraries

Comment: whenever you use libraries and need a built-in method from CI, use  $CI =& get_instance(); and then use it like so 

$CI->load->helper('url');
$CI->load->library('session');
$CI->config->item('base_url');
etc.... see http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/general/creating_libraries.html for more info

Comment: @Nassim I removed the controller extension from the libraries and used get_instance() to load other libraries. Now neither library loads :/

Comment: did you find a solution for your problem ?

Comment: Try to use the famous php way and see if it works .. $result_a = new liba() , $result_b = new libb() , then see if it works as you expected , if not then there must a problem with your code

Comment: @RobyMi Thanks. I have currently moved on to some other project. Will definitely try your suggestion when i get back. Appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

whenever you use libraries and helpers and need a built-in method from CI , use

```
$CI =& get_instance();
```

and then use it like so

```
$CI->load->helper('url');
$CI->load->library('session'); 
$CI->config->item('base_url');  //...etc
```

see [codeigniter.com/userguide2/general/creating_libraries.html](http://codeigniter.com/userguide2/general/creating_libraries.html)  for more info

---

or for a better solution, you can use codeigniter + HMVC to be able to call a controller from another and avoid any conflicts and ease your troubleshooting  see

[MVC vs HMVC for web application development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5454337/mvc-vs-hmvc-for-web-application-development/30301846#30301846)

Cheers !

Comment: Thanks Nassim. I have currently moved on to some other project. Will definitely try your suggestion when i get back. Appreciated!

Comment: Thanks for the response HMVC looks great for my next projects but my current project is in MVC CodeIgniter style. HMVC requires me to change the whole project into modules?? If yes, that is a lot of rework. I just need to be able to call a function each from 5-6 different php files from a controller. The php files are controllers right now but I'm flexible to make it a library etc. Is it possible to use HMVC without much code reorganising?

Comment: Alright, I am actually working on big project with codeigniter using just MVC, let me tell you that I was able to move all my code from MVC to HMVC in about 1 hour, because when you move your controllers to modules you can also move their libraries under the same module, so you won't loose anything, au contraire it will only gain flexibility . you can follow this video to get started https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDqwXpEQ8Pc

Comment: if you are not using codeigniter3 (like me) then following this video you will have an issue but this is how to fix it for codeigniter 2.x http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30554851/code-igniter-modular-extensions-access-level-to-mx-router-set-default-contro

Comment: There was a breakthrough in this issue yesterday. The problem was bad output from the libraries. I have fixed that and now I can normally load multiple libraries how I described in the question. However... I had to also use $CI =& getInstance in my libraries so as to use built in functions. So if you post it as the answer (your latest upvoted comment by me on the question) I will accept it.

Comment: And thank you so much for HMVC and how to migrate from MVC tutorials.. This is will be really helpful for my next projects! Cheers

Answer (score 2):

load multiple library in CI Just pass in it array

```
$this->load->library( array('liba', 'libb') );
```

and this notice because you not include

```
$CI =& get_instance();
```

inside your controller

Comment: Hey.. my mistake. I did passed them in array.. Didnt work. Let me edit my question.

Comment: its seams there is problem in library. Instead of calling library check your library code.

Comment: I think so from the beggining :)

Comment: @saty Like i said. If i just load one of either library. I do get results.

Comment: @saty  $CI =& get_instance();  - Why?!!

Comment: @saty Do i put that line in __construct() and use $CI instead of $this?? If yes, I tried. Didnt work

Comment: To access CodeIgniter's native resources within your library use the get_instance() function.

Answer (score 2):

Is the file in your controllers folder. If yes then You might not have properly extended your controller.
Like:

```
myController extends CI_Controller{}
```

else You need to use `$CI =& get_instance();` inside your file
and then use

```
$CI->load->library('your_library');
```

**Edit:**
**NOTE:** Check if your library file is capitalized inoyur folder structure like `Libb.php`

Comment: Yes my controller is in controllers folder. I have extended my controller to CI_Controller. And I have also used get_instance(). Failed with or without

Comment: If its in your controllers folder you dont have to user $CI =& get_instance(); you can simply use  $this->load->library('xyz')

Comment: Yes I know that. Like i said. It didnt work wither ways

Comment: All my files are "likethis" throughout. And class names are "Likethis"