# code igniter Modular Extensions - Access level to MX_Router::_set_default_controller() must be public (as in class CI_Router)

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-hmvc

I get the popular Modular Extensions - HMVC installed from

https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc

and set it up with codeigniter 2.2.2 **BUT** when everything should be working fine, I get this error

> Access level to MX_Router::_set_default_controller() must be public (as in class CI_Router) in C:..\application\third_party\MX\Router.php on line 241

Comment: The HMVC from here https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc go to downloads and then branches. I think only supports CI3

Comment: yes now they went on focusing on only CI3, but not the last stable version of ci 2.x

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Solution 1

I had to change several methods visibility  in Router.php , so I changed the following methods from `protected` to `public` to get it fixed

```
_set_default_controller()
_set_request()
_set_default_controller()
```

and it almost worked but now i get a warning above the familiar Welcome to CodeIgniter message

```
Message: Undefined property: MY_Router::$translate_uri_dashes
```

so I wrapped this property around an if not empty to bypass this property like so

```
if(!empty($this->translate_uri_dashes))
        {
            if ($this->translate_uri_dashes === TRUE)
            {
                foreach(range(0, 2) as $v)
                {
                    isset($segments[$v]) && $segments[$v] = str_replace('-', '_', $segments[$v]);
                }
            }
        }
```

and now it works!

---

### Solution 2

there is a ready HMVC-ci that can be downloaded from

http://lab.clearpixel.com.au/2011/10/modularise-your-codeigniter-2-applications-with-modular-extensions-%E2%80%93-hmvc/

but it's a ci 2.0.3 version not ci 2.2.2

### Solution 3 (best)

if you place the core files (MY_Loader and MY_Router) and the third-party folder (MX) from the preconfigured version of ci 2.0.3 (link above) inside the corresponding locations in the ci 2.2.2  it will work just fine.