# Codeigniter HMVC tutorials

Tags: codeigniter, hmvc, hmvc-codeigniter

I am looking for online tutorials or books that cover in-depth Codeigniter HMVC. Most of the online tutorials I have found only cover the very installation of HMVC. And I can not find any books at all on Codeigniter HMVC. All help greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc

Comment: I am using CI with HMVC , I wrote a post about it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30554851/code-igniter-modular-extensions-access-level-to-mx-router-set-default-contro

Comment: and you can watch this video too ,  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDqwXpEQ8Pc it will help + my previews link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best tutorial is this one 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8fy8E_C5_qQlist=PLBEpR3pmwCawDZ6FgNYoyvicEz4HrJPec

The tutorial it is made on codeigniter 2 and hmvc 2 vesions

But still the same setup to give you a idea.

The HMVC from here https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc only made now for codeigniter 3

They have not reloaded codeigniter 2 versions on.

The only difference really is that you need to make sure you have the first letter of your class and file names as Uppercase.

Comment: in this video he is using ci 2 , the HMVC on bitbucket.org does not work with ci 2 as I explained here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30554851/code-igniter-modular-extensions-access-level-to-mx-router-set-default-contro it's only for ci3 which is under development , the latest ci stable version is 2.2.2

Comment: I know that as I said on 3 line

Answer (score 1):

I don't want to be negative but, Codeigniter does not come with HMVC "out of the box" so there aren't any official documentation or books that covers the subject, however, there are some extensions that allow CI to use HMVC architecture, each extension has its own documentation, some are better documented than others.

some codeigniter HMVC extensions:

https://github.com/Crypt/Codeigniter-HMVC

https://github.com/jenssegers/codeigniter-hmvc-modules

this one needs some hacks for CI2.x (I didn't try it with CI3 yet)

https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc

this one is all in one (CI + HMVC extension)

http://lab.clearpixel.com.au/2011/10/modularise-your-codeigniter-2-applications-with-modular-extensions-%E2%80%93-hmvc/

Comment: This https://github.com/Crypt/Codeigniter-HMVC  looks like same as the bucket hmvc

Comment: yes, it's a fork, do you use HMVC in your projects  ?